# How to use pytractor with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use pytractor.

When I write import statement from pytractor.webdriver import Firefox

Firefox is not referenced-not found. Neither Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because, since Python 3.5, async is a protected keyword but is used in the mixins.py script. I renamed the variable and it fixed the problem